# How to use phpcpd command to check one file with all others

Tags: php, cpd

I have below file structure

```
ROOT_FOLDER
 |    
 +-- FRAMEWORK_FOLDER
 |  |  
 |  +-- FRAMEWORK_FILE1.php
 |  +-- FRAMEWORK_FILE2.php
 |  +-- FRAMEWORK_FILE3.php
 |  \-- FRAMEWORK_FILE4.php
 |    
 +-- MY_FOLDER
 |  |  
 |  +-- MY_FILE.php
```

Now I want to check code duplication in my file with all my source code files.
I am using below command

```
php phpcpd --log-pmd "MY_REPORT.xml" --names "ROOT_FOLDER/MY_FOLDER/MY_FILE.php" ./ROOT_FOLDER/FRAMEWORK_FOLDER/
```

This command gives me `no file found to scan` message

If I run below command

```
php phpcpd --log-pmd "MY_REPORT.xml" ./ROOT_FOLDER/FRAMEWORK_FOLDER/
```

It will compare my file with Source files but it also compares all source files with each other.

I am getting all duplication from my file as well as from my Framework's source files.

How can I only check my file with all of my Framework's source file while skipping all source files to compare with each other.

> Please let me know if there is an alternate to this approach. Any other php module or some other code package.